# BLE Mesh: Multi Device connect to mesh network

Tags: embedded, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32, mesh-network

I'm working with ESP32 (ESP-IDF) BLE Mesh and now I can work with it really well but there are some problems with it.

I have 5 nodes that All nodes are config in Proxy/relay mode. with one phone I can scan All of them and provision, and make a mesh network everything is ok, But if I provision nodes with device e.g."Phone-A" I cant see other nodes with any other device e.g."Phone-B". even I disconnect from mesh network.

1 - I cant connect Multi device phone to mesh Network and I dont know how can Handle it

2 - I dont know which mesh parameter should I Save in NVS flash that after reset esp32 the node can join network again automatically.

3 - and when a device "phone-A" is disconnected from network it's true that device "phone-B" join network and/or two device join mesh network simultaneously? if yes how? should I change nodes mode?

my code is exactly like this : [esp32 ble mesh Fast prov server Example](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/master/examples/bluetooth/esp_ble_mesh/ble_mesh_fast_provision/fast_prov_server/main/main.c) and I change it for my project and add some more code for pwm & led & ...

I asked this question in ESP32.com forums but theres no one that answer me.

Answer (score 1):

Open "menuconfig" in your IDE or terminal, then follow this: Bluetooth Mesh support --> Store Bluetooth Mesh key and configuration persistently

Just enable it and your code should work just fine